# Session Storage multiple output fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, output, session-storage

I'm working on a quote page and order page that use session storage to bring the information from two range sliders and the quoted price into the next page.

So far I have both range sliders working but am finding difficulty with the quoted price output element.

I cant use an Id as I have two output elements with the same value on the order page so I would need to use a class but am not sure if this would work with `sessionStorage.getItem`

I am also not sure what event listener I should use to activate the session storage on the quoted price.

below are two snippets and I have commented out and used question marks where I need help.

This is the code from my quote page.

```js
if (true) {

  var weightOut = document.getElementById('weightOutputId'),
      weightIn = document.getElementById('weightInputId'),
      distanceOut = document.getElementById('distanceOutputId'),
      distanceIn = document.getElementById('distanceInputId');
      //calPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('calP');  ???


  weightOut.value = sessionStorage.getItem('weightOutputId');
  weightIn.value = sessionStorage.getItem('weightInputId');
  distanceOut.value = sessionStorage.getItem('distanceOutputId');
  distanceIn.value = sessionStorage.getItem('distanceInputId');
  //calPrice.value = sessionStorage.getItem('calP');  ???

 // window.onload = function (){                      ??
 //  sessionStorage.setItem('calP', calPrice.value);  ???
 //}                                                  ??

  weightIn.addEventListener('input', function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('weightOutputId', weightOut.value);
    sessionStorage.setItem('weightInputId', weightIn.value);
  }, false);

   distanceIn.addEventListener('input', function () {
     sessionStorage.setItem('distanceOutputId', distanceOut.value);
     sessionStorage.setItem('distanceInputId', distanceIn.value);
   }, false);

}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" oninput="quote.value = distanceInputId.value * weightInputId.value +4;">
  <label for="weightOutputId" class="formQ">
    Weight (kg):
  </label>
  <output name="weightOutputName" id="weightOutputId">
    1
  </output>
  <input type="range" name="weightInputName" id="weightInputId" value="1" min="1" max="10" oninput="weightOutputId.value = weightInputId.value" class="formR">
  <label for="distanceInputId" class="formQ">
    Distance (km):
  </label>
  <output name="distanceOutputName" id="distanceOutputId">
    1
  </output>
  <input type="range" name="distanceInputName" id="distanceInputId" value="1" min="1" max="20" oninput="distanceOutputId.value = distanceInputId.value" class="formR">

  <span class="calP">
    Calculated Price: €
  </span>
  <output name="quote" class="calP">
    5
  </output>
</form>
```

This is the code from my order page.

```js
if (true) {

  var weightOut = document.getElementById('weightOutputId'),
      weightIn = document.getElementById('weightInputId'),
      distanceOut = document.getElementById('distanceOutputId'),
      distanceIn = document.getElementById('distanceInputId');
      //calPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('calP');  ???


  weightOut.value = sessionStorage.getItem('weightOutputId');
  weightIn.value = sessionStorage.getItem('weightInputId');
  distanceOut.value = sessionStorage.getItem('distanceOutputId');
  distanceIn.value = sessionStorage.getItem('distanceInputId');
  //calPrice.value = sessionStorage.getItem('calP');  ???

 // window.onload = function (){                      ??
 //  sessionStorage.setItem('calP', calPrice.value);  ???
 //}                                                  ??

  weightIn.addEventListener('input', function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('weightOutputId', weightOut.value);
    sessionStorage.setItem('weightInputId', weightIn.value);
  }, false);

   distanceIn.addEventListener('input', function () {
     sessionStorage.setItem('distanceOutputId', distanceOut.value);
     sessionStorage.setItem('distanceInputId', distanceIn.value);
   }, false);

}
```

```html
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="post" oninput="quote.value = distanceInputId.value * weightInputId.value +4, quoteT.value = distanceInputId.value * weightInputId.value +4;">
  <label for="weightInputId" class="formQ">
    Weight (kg):
  </label>
  <output name="weightOutputName" id="weightOutputId">
    1
  </output>
  <input type="range" name="weightInputName" id="weightInputId" value="1" min="1" max="10" oninput="weightOutputId.value = weightInputId.value" class="formR">
  <label for="distanceInputId" class="formQ">
    Distance (km):
  </label>
  <output name="distanceOutputName" id="distanceOutputId">
    1
  </output>
  <input type="range" name="distanceInputName" id="distanceInputId" value="1" min="1" max="20" oninput="distanceOutputId.value = distanceInputId.value" class="formR">
  <span class="calP">
    Calculated Price: €
  </span>
  <output name="quote" class="calP" id="keepNum">
    5
  </output>
  <!-- the rest of my form goes here-->
  <span class="calP">
    Calculated Price: €
  </span>
  <output name="quoteT" class="calP">
    5
  </output>
</form>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns not one but all elements with such class, so you will get several.

Comment: would `getElementsByClassName` not give all the price outputs the same value which is what I am after, but even trying `getElementById` with only one output element on the order page is proving difficult

Comment: Please, leave some comments under my answer so I may amend it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first try, let's edit it together.

```
'use strict'; // Strict mode is a good thing.

// ... Somehow you get a value for your price and store it:

const calculatedPrice = ...;
sessionStorage.setItem('calP', calculatedPrice)

// ... Then you read it and fill multiple fields with it.

let calculatedPrice = parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('calP'));
if (!calculatedPrice && calculatedPrice !== 0) {
  calculatedPrice = ...; // Get it somehow.
  sessionStorage.setItem('calP', calculatedPrice); // Update it.
}

// Now render all the fields!
const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('calP'));
elements.forEach(function(el) { el.innerText = calculatedPrice; })
```

`el.innerText` fills the whole content of an element. If you need to fill it like a template with "holes" then it will require more code — ask me for it).